# Out of memory with low CPU consumption

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, high-load

I'm trying to tune some kind of hi-load application, which streaming data from one cloud to other with some preprocessing.
The specific of my application is extensive memory usage and low CPU consumption.
I monitored the app with jconsole and reached some interesting picture - cpu is loaded up to 15% and I'm still catching the out of memory error.

Manual triggering for "Perform GC" from jconsole is clearing a lot of memory in all generations so I assume that there is no memory leak in application.

My application is running on mesos/marathon, so I tried to switch between single virtual CPU to multi CPU with various GCs (-XX:+UseG1GC; -XX:+UseParallelGC without other tuning) and the picture is actually the same;

- So, why GC doesn't use the CPU to free memory?
- Can we tune GC for more frequent/proper work?

Runtime metrics:
[image]

System configuration:
[image]

Comment: What does "out of memory" mean in this context? do you get OuOfMemoryException? That seems unlikely since you say the memory is freed when you manually invoke GC. If you don't get an exception, what is your problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're allocating something so big that even a GC wouldn't have cleared sufficient memory, in which case I suppose the system can throw it without even bothering to do a GC.

Comment: Get heap dump and see what's there in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I should share the result of my investigations.

"Out of memory" - is what I've got from DevOps-guy, and first thing I imagine - OutOfMemoryException. So, thanks Alex for [clarifying question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407713/out-of-memory-with-low-cpu-consumption/43492305#comment-73874840).

In my case It was OOMKill in docker environment from underlying OS. I allocated 1G for container and restricted the java heap size with 736m.
But my application used netty which allocated own memory buffers bypassing the heap. So, when more connection appears the netty allocated more direct buffers which leads to OOMKill in spite of healthy heap.

Comment: I guess this is a good explanation and you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

GC runs when there is need for application to free the memory. GC is expensive operation and it will run only when it is in need.
I am not sure why you are trying to related CPU utilization with running GC. CPU utilization is nothing to do with running GC application. 
If VM thread decides GC to run it will Pause all the application threads running (Safepointing) and allow GC to perform operation, so amount of CPU Java is using remains the same, doesn't matter how much CPU you are left with.

There are many GC flags that can be used to finetune your application, i won't be able to suggest any as not sure what exactly your application is?

Possible below links will help you
http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-tune-java-garbage-collection/
https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/garbage-collection-gc-tuning-guide-461504616.html

You should know where you are getting OOM, Old generation, Metaspace, Codegen or native based on that you can fine tune with heap options

Comment: Hi Fairoz, thank you for the answer and links! I related the CPU usage with GC activity cause we can have such problems as "GC overhead limit exceeded". When User threads are stopped and GC is processing th memory - it consumes the CPU. So that combination seemed strange for me: memory problems & low CPU consumption.

Comment: Also, i [realized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407713/out-of-memory-with-low-cpu-consumption/43492305#43491520) that it wasn't GC - related problem